# Bash wrapping parts of a variable in quotes when expanded

Tags: bash, find

I'm trying to recursively find c and header files in a script, while avoiding globbing out any that exist in the current directory.

```
FILE_MATCH_LIST='"*.c","*.cc","*.cpp","*.h","*.hh","*.hpp"'
FILE_MATCH_REGEX=$(echo "$FILE_MATCH_LIST" | sed 's/,/ -o -name /g')
FILE_MATCH_REGEX="-name $FILE_MATCH_REGEX"
```

This does exactly what I want it to:

```
 + FILE_MATCH_REGEX='-name "*.c" -o -name "*.cc" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hh" -o -name "*.hpp"'
```

Now, if I call find with that string (in quotes), it maintains the leading and trailing quotes and breaks find:

```
files=$(find $root_dir "$FILE_MATCH_REGEX" | grep -v $GREP_IGNORE_LIST)

+ find [directory] '-name "*.c" -o -name "*.cc" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hh" -o -name "*.hpp"'
```

This results in a "unknown predicate" error from find, because the entire predicate is single quoted.

If I drop the quotes from the variable in the find command, I get a strange behavior:

```
files=$(find $root_dir $FILE_MATCH_REGEX | grep -v $GREP_IGNORE_LIST)

+  find [directory] -name '"*.c"' -o -name '"*.cc"' -o -name '"*.cpp"' -o -name '"*.h"' -o -name '"*.hh"' -o -name '"*.hpp"'
```

Where are these single quotes coming from? They exist if I echo that variable as well, but they aren't there in the command when I'm actually setting the `$FILE_MATCH_REGEX` (As seen at the beginning of the question).

This of course also breaks find, because it's looking for the actual double quoted string, instead of expanding the `*.h` etc.

How do I get these strings into find without all of these quoting woes?

Comment: `find` needs to see the pieces as individual arguments.  As a first step, make `FILE_MATCH_REGEX` an **array**, where each array element consists of one argument for `find`. Then use this array for passing the parameters to find, as `"${FILE_MATCH_REGEX[@]}"`.

Comment: See [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050): I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!

Comment: The shell is still globbing the element (and stripping the quotes that are necessary to send to find) as I pass it through the processing (to add the arguments to send it to find): `arr=('*.c' '*.h'); for i in ${arr[@]}; do $FILE_MATCH_REGEX+=("-o" "-name" "$i"); done`

Comment: The quotes aren't necessary to send to find unless there are literal quote characters in the filenames you're trying to match. You need to quote `"${arr[@]}"` to protect its contents from pathname expansion.

Comment: Also your assignment is a little off, should be `FILE_MATCH_REGEX+=("-o" "-name" "$i")`

Comment: @tjm3772 I disagree. Running `find . -name *.c` without quotes, with a .c file in the current directory, will not give the expected results

Comment: It gives the wrong result because unquoted globs are subject to pathname expansion **by the shell**. Even if you add quotes like `find . -name "*.c"` your shell just removes them and makes a note not to expand the glob. `find` never sees those quote characters.

Comment: Sure, but that's the exact problem I'm having in the original question. The shell is doing what it wants and then deciding to glob and/or add random quotes because of word splitting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fleshing out the array answer:

```
#!/bin/bash
patterns=( '*.c' '*.cc' '*.h' '*.hh' )
find_args=( "-name" "${patterns[0]}" )
for (( i=1 ; i < "${#patterns[@]}" ; i++ )) ; do
  find_args+=( "-o" "-name" "${patterns[i]}" )
done
find [directory] "${find_args[@]}"
```

Also, to clear up the misconception around quotes, if you `echo` the last line the output might not be what you expect:

```
echo find [directory] "${find_args[@]}"
# outputs: find [directory] -name *.c -o -name *.cc -o -name *.h -o -name *.hh
```

Where are the quotes? Your shell removed them after it was done with them. Quotes are not `find` syntax, they are shell syntax that tell the shell how to interpret (or perhaps how NOT to interpret) your command line.

The reason for the strange behavior in your debug output is that the quotes in your data are *literal* quotes, not shell syntax quotes that get removed during command parsing. The debugger is just trying to point out the distinction.

Some useful resources on the Bash wiki:

- [BashParser](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser) explains how your command line gets parsed and executed
- [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) explains why embedding quotes in your data isn't sufficient

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU `find` - adjust to your liking:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#FILE_MATCH_LIST='"*.c","*.cc","*.cpp","*.h","*.hh","*.hpp"'
FILE_MATCH_LIST='.*/.*\.(c|cc|cpp|h|hh|hpp)'

find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex "${FILE_MATCH_LIST}"
```

Comment: Can you explain why `.*/.*` is part of this regex? Wouldn't a single `.*` cover all the recursive cases?

Comment: @BrydonGibson, yes - you're right: `.*` should be enough to recurse. 
Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the workaround. I've upvoted this but I'm hesitant to mark it as correct because it doesn't _technically_ answer the question, even though the correct answer is "you're dumb don't do this"